# High Latency in Flink's keyBy Operation

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Despite setting setBufferTimeout to 0, I've measured that the latency of the keyBy operation is usually between 0-1 ms in most cases. However, as the program continues to run, I occasionally observe latencies reaching several thousand milliseconds. Is this normal behavior?

In this code, I recorded the time before and after the keyBy operation, and then I noticed the situation that I mentioned earlier.

```
originalTrajectories = originalTrajectories.keyBy(t -> t.getGridID()).map(new MapFunction<Trajectory1, Trajectory1>() {
            @Override
            public Trajectory1 map(Trajectory1 value) {
                value.t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return value;
            }
        });

queryTrajectories = queryTrajectories.keyBy(t -> t.getGridID()).map(new MapFunction<Trajectory1, Trajectory1>() {
            @Override
            public Trajectory1 map(Trajectory1 value) {
                value.t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return value;
            }
        });


DataStream<Tuple4<Long, Long, Trajectory1, Trajectory1>> timedResultTrajectories = originalTrajectories
            .keyBy(t -> t.getGridID())
            .intervalJoin(queryTrajectories.keyBy(t -> t.getGridID()))
            .between(Time.milliseconds(-slideStep * 1000), Time.milliseconds(slideStep * 1000))
            .process(new ProcessJoinFunction<Trajectory1, Trajectory1, Tuple4<Trajectory1, Trajectory1, Long, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(Trajectory1 t1, Trajectory1 t2, ProcessJoinFunction<Trajectory1, Trajectory1, Tuple4<Trajectory1, Trajectory1, Long, Double>>.Context ctx, Collector<Tuple4<Trajectory1, Trajectory1, Long, Double>> out) {
                    if (Math.abs(t1.getTimestamp() - t2.getTimestamp()) == 0) {
                        Double distance = calculateClosestPairDistance(t1, t2);
                        if (distance <= queryRadius) {
                            out.collect(Tuple4.of(t1, t2, System.currentTimeMillis(), distance));
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: You have three keyBys in this workflow - which one(s) are you using for latency tracking, and how are you tracking the latency? Also the first two keyBy() operations (on the original and query trajectory streams, before the join) aren't necessary.

Comment: Originally, I did not have the first two keyBy operations. However, since an intervalJoin follows the third keyBy, I was concerned that the intervalJoin might introduce latency. To measure the latency, I recorded the time before the first two keyBy operations and then again in the map function following the keyBy. I used these timestamps to calculate the latency.

Comment: Hmm, OK - have you tried enabling object reuse, to reduce the GC load?

Answer (score 0):

Occasional hiccups in latency are certainly possible. If it's as long as a few seconds, as you've indicated, I would look at garbage collection as a possible cause.

Flink 1.18 includes experimental support for Java 17. If GC is indeed the problem, you might consider experimenting with Java 17 and its options for improved GC. And if you want to go further, Flink's master branch now includes experimental support for JDK 21, in which ZGC has been updated to add multigenerational GC.

Based on what others have reported, I would expect significant improvements to worst-case latency with Flink 1.18 using Java 17 and ZGC, but with some decrease in throughput. Initial experiments with Java 21 showed promising improvements to the throughput.

Comment: I am using JDK 8 and Flink 1.16. After conducting some tests, I found that one of the TaskManagers experienced 300 runs of the G1 Young Generation garbage collection, totaling 90,443 milliseconds. Then, the G1 Old Generation ran just once, but it took a staggering 77,214 milliseconds, leading to a heartbeat timeout and the termination of the program. How should I address this issue? For example, would upgrading to a newer version or employing other methods be beneficial?

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer, basically saying that upgrading to Flink 1.18 and Java 17 should noticeably reduce GC pauses.